# White spaces in data table not working properly in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

Not getting the input request properly if the given input string contains space in-between in cucumber data table. Also, I did delete the trailing and leading space to ensure there are no hidden illegal characters but still received the inputs incorrectly in java code. Any advice would certainly help.

**Feature:Foo**

```
  @foo
  Scenario Outline: sample run
    Then send request <aoo> <boo> <coo> <doo>                                                  
    Examples:                                                                                                                 
      | aoo | boo | coo            | doo  | 
      | 200 | xyx | Do not disturb | true |
      
    @Then("^send request (.*) (.*) (.*) (.*)$")
    public void send_request(String aoo, String boo, String coo, String doo) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("aoo " + aoo);
        System.out.println("boo " + boo);
        System.out.println("coo " + coo);
        System.out.println("doo " + doo);
    }
```

**Expected Output:-**

```
aoo 200
boo xyx
coo Do not disturb
doo true
```

**Actual Output:-**

```
aoo 200 xyz Do
boo not
coo disturb
doo true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(.*) is greedy and matches any character. You have to limit them. If possible try to use other data types. `aoo` -> `int`, `doo` -> `boolean`

```
@foo
Scenario Outline: sample run
    Then send request "<aoo>" "<boo>" "<coo>" "<doo>"
    Examples:
        | aoo | boo | coo            | doo  |
        | 200 | xyx | Do not disturb | true |
```

```java
@Then("^send request \"(.*)\" \"(.*)\" \"(.*)\" \"(.*)\"$")
public void send_request(String aoo, String boo, String coo, String doo) throws Throwable {
    // omitted code
}
```